# Polling S3 bucket for files and processing using spring integration aws

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-s3, spring-integration

I need to poll a S3 bucket for files and pick them up and process them as soon as any file becomes available. I need to do this using Spring Integration and spring-integration-aws.
So the code i have so far looks like this:

```
public AmazonS3 amazonS3 = new AmazonS3Client(new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey));`enter code here`


@Bean
public S3InboundFileSynchronizer s3InboundFileSynchronizer() {
    S3InboundFileSynchronizer synchronizer = new S3InboundFileSynchronizer(amazonS3);
    synchronizer.setDeleteRemoteFiles(true);
    synchronizer.setPreserveTimestamp(true);
    synchronizer.setRemoteDirectory(s3BucketName.concat("/").concat(s3InboundFolder));
    synchronizer.setFilter(new S3RegexPatternFileListFilter(".*\\.dat\\.{0,1}\\d{0,2}"));
    return synchronizer;
}

@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(value = "s3FilesChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "10"))
public S3InboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource s3InboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource() {
    S3InboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource messageSource =
            new S3InboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource(s3InboundFileSynchronizer());
    messageSource.setAutoCreateLocalDirectory(true);
    messageSource.setLocalDirectory(new File(inboundDir));
    messageSource.setLocalFilter(new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<File>());
    return messageSource;
}

@Bean
public PollableChannel s3FilesChannel() {
    return new QueueChannel();
}
```

and then i have a FileReadingFlow like this:

```
@Bean
IntegrationFlow fileReadingFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows
              .from(s3InboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource(),
                      e -> e.poller(p -> p.fixedDelay(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)))
            .handle(fileProcessor())
            .get();
}
```

but i keep getting a 'Cannot assign requested address: bind' error. Heres the stack trace -

```
  2017-04-13 17:16:45.315  INFO 4440 --- [  restartedMain] eEncryptablePropertySourcesPostProcessor : Converting PropertySource servletConfigInitParams [org.springframework.core.env.PropertySource$StubPropertySource] to EncryptablePropertySourceWrapper
2017-04-13 17:16:45.315  INFO 4440 --- [  restartedMain] eEncryptablePropertySourcesPostProcessor : Converting PropertySource servletContextInitParams [org.springframework.core.env.PropertySource$StubPropertySource] to EncryptablePropertySourceWrapper
2017-04-13 17:16:45.315  INFO 4440 --- [  restartedMain] eEncryptablePropertySourcesPostProcessor : Converting PropertySource systemProperties [org.springframework.core.env.MapPropertySource] to EncryptableMapPropertySourceWrapper
2017-04-13 17:16:45.315  INFO 4440 --- [  restartedMain] eEncryptablePropertySourcesPostProcessor : Converting PropertySource systemEnvironment [org.springframework.core.env.SystemEnvironmentPropertySource] to EncryptableMapPropertySourceWrapper
2017-04-13 17:16:45.315  INFO 4440 --- [  restartedMain] eEncryptablePropertySourcesPostProcessor : Converting PropertySource random [org.springframework.boot.context.config.RandomValuePropertySource] to EncryptablePropertySourceWrapper
2017-04-13 17:16:45.325  INFO 4440 --- [  restartedMain] eEncryptablePropertySourcesPostProcessor : Converting PropertySource applicationConfig: [classpath:/application-dev.properties] [org.springframework.core.env.PropertiesPropertySource] to EncryptableMapPropertySourceWrapper
2017-04-13 17:16:45.325  INFO 4440 --- [  restartedMain] eEncryptablePropertySourcesPostProcessor : Converting PropertySource applicationConfig: [classpath:/application.properties] [org.springframework.core.env.PropertiesPropertySource] to EncryptableMapPropertySourceWrapper
2017-04-13 17:16:45.325  INFO 4440 --- [  restartedMain] eEncryptablePropertySourcesPostProcessor : Converting PropertySource refresh [org.springframework.core.env.MapPropertySource] to EncryptableMapPropertySourceWrapper
2017-04-13 17:16:45.345  INFO 4440 --- [  restartedMain] faultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor : No bean named 'taskScheduler' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default ThreadPoolTaskScheduler will be created.
2017-04-13 17:16:46.515  INFO 4440 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.retry.annotation.RetryConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.retry.annotation.RetryConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6d590986] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-04-13 17:16:47.035  INFO 4440 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$77957161] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-04-13 17:16:47.525  INFO 4440 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.f.config.PropertiesFactoryBean     : Loading properties file from URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/atare/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.integration/spring-integration-core/4.3.5.RELEASE/5fb7134905e7cd34dfd6e95b4e58102b0e09cf38/spring-integration-core-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/META-INF/spring.integration.default.properties]
2017-04-13 17:16:47.535  INFO 4440 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'integrationGlobalProperties' of type [class org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-04-13 17:16:47.545  INFO 4440 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'integrationGlobalProperties' of type [class java.util.Properties] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-04-13 17:16:51.905  INFO 4440 --- [  restartedMain] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (https)
2017-04-13 17:16:51.945  INFO 4440 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2017-04-13 17:16:51.955  INFO 4440 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.6
2017-04-13 17:16:52.725  INFO 4440 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2017-04-13 17:16:52.725  INFO 4440 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 17034 ms
2017-04-13 17:16:56.803  INFO 4440 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2017-04-13 17:16:56.823  INFO 4440 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'metricsFilter' to: [/*]
2017-04-13 17:16:56.823  INFO 4440 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-04-13 17:16:56.823  INFO 4440 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2017-04-13 17:16:56.823  INFO 4440 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2017-04-13 17:16:56.823  INFO 4440 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2017-04-13 17:16:56.823  INFO 4440 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'webRequestLoggingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-04-13 17:16:56.823  INFO 4440 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'applicationContextIdFilter' to: [/*]
2017-04-13 17:20:03.623  INFO 4440 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@31ea2fb2: startup date [Thu Apr 13 17:16:35 PDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-04-13 17:20:04.313  INFO 4440 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2017-04-13 17:20:04.313  INFO 4440 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2017-04-13 17:20:05.033  INFO 4440 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-04-13 17:20:05.033  INFO 4440 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-04-13 17:20:06.797  INFO 4440 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-04-13 17:20:11.022  INFO 4440 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Initializing ExecutorService  'taskScheduler'
2017-04-13 17:20:16.399  INFO 4440 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/logfile || /logfile.json],methods=[GET || HEAD]}" onto public void org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.LogFileMvcEndpoint.invoke(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws javax.servlet.ServletException,java.io.IOException
2017-04-13 17:20:16.410  INFO 4440 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/heapdump || /heapdump.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/octet-stream]}" onto public void org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.HeapdumpMvcEndpoint.invoke(boolean,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.io.IOException,javax.servlet.ServletException
2017-04-13 17:20:16.436  INFO 4440 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/trace || /trace.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2017-04-13 17:20:16.445  INFO 4440 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/env/{name:.*}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EnvironmentMvcEndpoint.value(java.lang.String)
2017-04-13 17:20:16.447  INFO 4440 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/env || /env.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2017-04-13 17:20:16.454  INFO 4440 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/configprops || /configprops.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2017-04-13 17:20:16.461  INFO 4440 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/dump || /dump.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2017-04-13 17:20:16.469  INFO 4440 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/autoconfig || /autoconfig.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2017-04-13 17:20:16.475  INFO 4440 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/info || /info.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2017-04-13 17:20:16.482  INFO 4440 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/health || /health.json],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.HealthMvcEndpoint.invoke(java.security.Principal)
2017-04-13 17:20:16.517  INFO 4440 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/metrics/{name:.*}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.MetricsMvcEndpoint.value(java.lang.String)
2017-04-13 17:20:16.519  INFO 4440 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/metrics || /metrics.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2017-04-13 17:20:16.524  INFO 4440 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/mappings || /mappings.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2017-04-13 17:20:16.530  INFO 4440 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/beans || /beans.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2017-04-13 17:20:19.238  INFO 4440 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2017-04-13 17:20:22.018  INFO 4440 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2017-04-13 17:20:22.189  INFO 4440 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'integrationMbeanExporter' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2017-04-13 17:20:22.273  INFO 4440 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located managed bean 'integrationMbeanExporter': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.integration.monitor:name=integrationMbeanExporter,type=IntegrationMBeanExporter]
2017-04-13 17:20:22.685  INFO 4440 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2017-04-13 17:20:22.688  INFO 4440 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Registering MessageChannel errorChannel
2017-04-13 17:20:22.730  INFO 4440 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Located managed bean 'org.springframework.integration:type=MessageChannel,name=errorChannel': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.integration:type=MessageChannel,name=errorChannel]
2017-04-13 17:20:23.373  INFO 4440 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Registering MessageChannel s3FilesChannel
2017-04-13 17:20:23.396  INFO 4440 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Located managed bean 'org.springframework.integration:type=MessageChannel,name=s3FilesChannel': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.integration:type=MessageChannel,name=s3FilesChannel]
2017-04-13 17:20:23.672  INFO 4440 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Registering MessageChannel nullChannel
2017-04-13 17:20:23.701  INFO 4440 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Located managed bean 'org.springframework.integration:type=MessageChannel,name=nullChannel': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.integration:type=MessageChannel,name=nullChannel]
2017-04-13 17:20:23.900  INFO 4440 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Registering MessageChannel toMessageProcessing
2017-04-13 17:20:23.924  INFO 4440 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Located managed bean 'org.springframework.integration:type=MessageChannel,name=toMessageProcessing': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.integration:type=MessageChannel,name=toMessageProcessing]
2017-04-13 17:20:24.271  INFO 4440 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Registering MessageChannel fileReadingFlow.channel#0
2017-04-13 17:20:24.298  INFO 4440 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Located managed bean 'org.springframework.integration:type=MessageChannel,name=fileReadingFlow.channel#0': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.integration:type=MessageChannel,name=fileReadingFlow.channel#0]
2017-04-13 17:20:24.746  INFO 4440 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Registering MessageChannel errorSubFlow.input
2017-04-13 17:20:24.803  INFO 4440 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Located managed bean 'org.springframework.integration:type=MessageChannel,name=errorSubFlow.input': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.integration:type=MessageChannel,name=errorSubFlow.input]
2017-04-13 17:20:25.288  INFO 4440 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Located managed bean 'org.springframework.integration:type=MessageHandler,name=errorChannel,bean=anonymous': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.integration:type=MessageHandler,name=errorChannel,bean=anonymous]
2017-04-13 17:20:25.565  INFO 4440 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Located managed bean 'org.springframework.integration:type=MessageHandler,name=errorSubFlow.input,bean=anonymous': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.integration:type=MessageHandler,name=errorSubFlow.input,bean=anonymous]
2017-04-13 17:20:25.870  INFO 4440 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Located managed bean 'org.springframework.integration:type=MessageHandler,name=fileReadingFlow.channel#0,bean=anonymous': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.integration:type=MessageHandler,name=fileReadingFlow.channel#0,bean=anonymous]
2017-04-13 17:20:26.108  INFO 4440 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Located managed bean 'org.springframework.integration:type=MessageSource,name=applicationConfig.s3InboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.inboundChannelAdapter,bean=endpoint': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.integration:type=MessageSource,name=applicationConfig.s3InboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.inboundChannelAdapter,bean=endpoint]
2017-04-13 17:20:26.325  INFO 4440 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Located managed bean 'org.springframework.integration:type=ManagedEndpoint,name=org.springframework.integration.config.SourcePollingChannelAdapterFactoryBean#0,bean=endpoint': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.integration:type=ManagedEndpoint,name=org.springframework.integration.config.SourcePollingChannelAdapterFactoryBean#0,bean=endpoint]
2017-04-13 17:20:26.376  INFO 4440 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Registered endpoint without MessageSource: org.springframework.integration:type=ManagedEndpoint,name=org.springframework.integration.config.SourcePollingChannelAdapterFactoryBean#0,bean=endpoint
2017-04-13 17:20:26.576  INFO 4440 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase 0
2017-04-13 17:20:27.278  INFO 4440 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.i.e.SourcePollingChannelAdapter      : started applicationConfig.s3InboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.inboundChannelAdapter
2017-04-13 17:20:27.279  INFO 4440 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {bridge} as a subscriber to the 'errorSubFlow.input' channel
2017-04-13 17:20:27.281  INFO 4440 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : Channel 'application:dev.errorSubFlow.input' has 1 subscriber(s).
2017-04-13 17:20:27.282  INFO 4440 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#0
2017-04-13 17:20:27.284  INFO 4440 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {service-activator} as a subscriber to the 'fileReadingFlow.channel#0' channel
2017-04-13 17:20:27.285  INFO 4440 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : Channel 'application:dev.fileReadingFlow.channel#0' has 1 subscriber(s).
2017-04-13 17:20:27.285  INFO 4440 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#2
2017-04-13 17:20:27.286  INFO 4440 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase 1073741823
2017-04-13 17:20:27.290  INFO 4440 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.i.endpoint.PollingConsumer           : started org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#1
2017-04-13 17:20:27.294  INFO 4440 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.i.e.SourcePollingChannelAdapter      : started org.springframework.integration.config.SourcePollingChannelAdapterFactoryBean#0
2017-04-13 17:20:27.714 ERROR 4440 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol      : Failed to start end point associated with ProtocolHandler [https-jsse-nio-50.18.174.237-8080]
java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: bind
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:228)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:874)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:590)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:969)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:225)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:233)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:178)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:297)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:145)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:545)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175)
    at com.nike.nikecoupagateway.inboundasnservice.InboundAsnApplication.main(InboundAsnApplication.java:11)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)

2017-04-13 17:20:27.723 ERROR 4440 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Failed to start connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]

org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:225)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:233)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:178)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:297)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:145)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:545)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175)
    at com.nike.nikecoupagateway.inboundasnservice.InboundAsnApplication.main(InboundAsnApplication.java:11)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: service.getName(): "Tomcat";  Protocol handler start failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:976)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: bind
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:228)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:874)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:590)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:969)
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Description:
The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8080 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured.
Action:
Verify the connector's configuration, identify and stop any process that's listening on port 8080, or configure this application to listen on another port.
```

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Spring Boot with an embedded Tomcat server and port 8080 is already in use...

> The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8080 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured.

You need to stop the other server, change the `server.port` property to some other port (0 will use a random port), or disable boot's embedded tomcat server. See the [Spring Boot reference manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/).

This has nothing to do with Spring Integration or Spring AWS.

Comment: Thanks Gary! I added the following lines to my property file and that solved the tomcat issue.                                                       spring.main.web-environment=false
server.port=7943

Answer (score 1):

Gary is 100% correct in the diagnosis.  But I have to ask why you're recreating existing AWS functionality.  S3 has 3 different ways to notify you when an object is created.  It doesn't have quite the regular expression that you need for your file name but it can notify a Lambda, an SNS topic or an SQS queue.  A trivial Lambda would just be:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.List;

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestStreamHandler;
import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath;


public class S3EventLambdaHandler implements RequestStreamHandler {
    public void handleRequest(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream, Context context) {

        try {
            List<String> keys = JsonPath.read(inputStream, "$.Records[*].s3.object.key");

            for( String nextKey: keys )
                System.out.println(nextKey);
        }
        catch( IOException ioe ) {
            context.getLogger().log("caught IOException reading input stream");
        }
    }
}
```

which is based on a Lambda I have to catch S3 events already.  This only prints the file name but you could easily change it to do more.  The Lambda could just as easily call a rest service or something to tell you the file is available but polling S3 is just not needed.

Just a thought.  With a nearly 4 minute startup time this is a very heavy weight thing - there are possibly ways to lighten the overhead.