# AWS Lambda : Java : Kinesis Events

Tags: java, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

I'm having trouble finding examples of what I'm trying to do...

I'd like to create a Lambda function in Java. I thought I'd always use Javascript for Lambda functions, but in this case I'll end up re-using application logic already written in Java, so it makes sense.

In the past I've written Javascript Lambda functions that are triggered by Kinesis events. Super simple, function receives the events as a parameter, do something, voila. I'd like to do the same thing with Java. Really simple :

Kinesis Event(s) -> Trigger Function -> (Java) Receive Kinesis Events, do something with them

Anyone have experience with this kind of use case?

Comment: Your question is not specific. As general as your question is - the answer - it is the same regardless of the language run by the lambda.

Comment: I gave some code for a Java Lambda for S3 events [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43403892/polling-s3-bucket-for-files-and-processing-using-spring-integration-aws/43404351#43404351).  They should be similar.

Comment: johni, as is shown in the answer, module.exports = function(event, context){} is definitely not the same as public PutRecordsResult eventHandler(KinesisEvent event, Context context){}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is some sample code I wrote to demonstrate the same concept internally. This code forwards events from one stream to another.

Note this code does not handle retries if there are errors in forwarding, nor is it meant to be performant in a production environment, but it does demonstrate how to handle the records from the publishing stream.

```
import com.amazonaws.regions.Region;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
import com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesisClient;
import com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.model.PutRecordsRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.model.PutRecordsRequestEntry;
import com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.model.PutRecordsResult;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.LambdaLogger;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.KinesisEvent;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class KinesisToKinesis {

    private LambdaLogger logger;
    final private AmazonKinesisClient kinesisClient = new AmazonKinesisClient();

    public PutRecordsResult eventHandler(KinesisEvent event, Context context) {
        logger = context.getLogger();
        if (event == null || event.getRecords() == null) {
            logger.log("Event contains no data" + System.lineSeparator());
            return null;
        } else {
            logger.log("Received " + event.getRecords().size() +
                " records from " + event.getRecords().get(0).getEventSourceARN() + System.lineSeparator());
        }

        final Long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        // set up the client
        Region region;
        final Map<String, String> environmentVariables = System.getenv();
        if (environmentVariables.containsKey("AWS_REGION")) {
            region = Region.getRegion(Regions.fromName(environmentVariables.get("AWS_REGION")));
        } else {
            region = Region.getRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2);
            logger.log("Using default region: " + region.toString() + System.lineSeparator());
        }
        kinesisClient.setRegion(region);

        Long elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        logger.log("Finished setup in " + elapsed + " ms" + System.lineSeparator());

        PutRecordsRequest putRecordsRequest = new PutRecordsRequest().withStreamName("usagecounters-global");
        List<PutRecordsRequestEntry> putRecordsRequestEntryList = event.getRecords().parallelStream()
            .map(r -> new PutRecordsRequestEntry()
                    .withData(ByteBuffer.wrap(r.getKinesis().getData().array()))
                    .withPartitionKey(r.getKinesis().getPartitionKey()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

        putRecordsRequest.setRecords(putRecordsRequestEntryList);

        elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        logger.log("Processed " + putRecordsRequest.getRecords().size() +
            " records in " + elapsed + " ms" + System.lineSeparator());

        PutRecordsResult putRecordsResult = kinesisClient.putRecords(putRecordsRequest);
        elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        logger.log("Forwarded " + putRecordsRequest.getRecords().size() +
                " records to Kinesis " + putRecordsRequest.getStreamName() +
                " in " + elapsed + " ms" + System.lineSeparator());
        return putRecordsResult;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks devonlazarus, this is a helpful example to start with! It was particularly the entry point and how the event parameter is typed that I was confused with, since in JS it's the same regardless of the incoming event. Cheers!